# twitter bootstrap margin-left -20px issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue using twitter bootstrap on my webpage http://scrapp.site90.com/ . Header is wrapped in container and has .row around it, but seems that because of margin-left: -20px this row cannot align with other content. Is it  possible to fix it? I tried to change value of margin-left, but then layout gets really messed up.

Comment: not sure what you mean. seems fine in my ff and chrome

Comment: your site address is asking for captcha.. people might not become comfortable accessing it. Please check that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `span*` you could use `pull-left` on the `H1`..

```
<div class="row">
        <h1 class="pull-left">Take a look at our work to see what we mean</h1>
        <div>
        <ul class="social inline pull-right">
            <li>..</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```